# How to correctly use segue here?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Then I call this method I want to have segue. Is it right?

```
 - (void)showMapViewController {

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController" sender:self];
 }

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MapViewController"])
     {
      UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.sourceViewController;
      LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
      [loginViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController" sender:self];
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but this is wrong! Do you even have a segue defined with the identifier "MapViewController"? I think what you are trying to do is pushing a VC to a navigation controller, is this true?

Comment: You should give more context since I don't understand the relationship between your 'addplayer'-segue and your mapviewcontroller segue

Comment: sorry for 'add player', it - MapViewController. I want call showMapViewController method and push VC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to  create segue in storyboard and give a unique identifier. It can be perform automaticaly if you set this on some button action, e.g. if you create a segue on button action an want to push a navigation controller. When ever that button will be push segue will be perform automaticlay. In this case if you want to do some custom coding to set some properties etc. then you should implement this delegate method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"])
     {
     // Here you can get source and destination view controllers and can perform some custom tasks.
     }
 }
```

You can also perform segue by code if you want to, for that you have to call this method.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueidentifer" sender:self];
```

For this you have to create a segue in storyboard by clt+drag from one view controller to other(source -> destination) and give an identifier.